# Adding « qui soit/soient » to the superlative

Tags: expressions

> Nous ne ménageons pas nos efforts pour fournir à nos clients les fruits et les légumes **les plus frais qui soient**.

I wonder if you add « qui soit/soient » to the superlative only when you are boasting of its quality. If so, I imagine that it wouldn’t make sense to use this expression with an adjective with a negative connotation, as in «  le plus mauvais qui soit ».

Comment: It's the same as in English: *the worst there is*. Your question is in English, so I'm guessing you are familiar with this usage in English.

Comment: Je serais curieuse de savoir quelle méthode de langue tu utilises, c'est impressionnant cette maîtrise de la langue pour quelqu'un qui vient de commencer le français.

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE Ça fait plusieurs années qu'elle étudie le français... Qu'est-ce qui te fait croire qu'elle vient de commencer ? Il lui arrive même de dire des choses comme "en 3 ans j'ai jamais entendu cette expression, pourtant on me dit que c'est très courant".

Comment: Pas Drew, elle n'a rien dit en français. C'est Ah alone-zee qui parle d'une méthode de langue.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Hi. Colour me confused! Because I don't recall ever saying "learning for 3 years", or anything to that effect... Perhaps, you misread some of my past comments? Anyway, I've been learning French exactly as long as I've been on this site: 7 months now. One year ago, "an, do, toewa" were just about the only French words I knew! :)

Comment: @Ahalone-zee My bad ! That's crazy, I remember vividly that in a question you said something like "it's the first time I see this since I started [time] ago", and I'm starting to think I made that up or mixed with something else, I can't find your question again. I guess 7 month is pretty quick then !

Comment: @Ahalone-zee Now I'm interested in your "unorthodox and extreme" method :) Et excuse-moi PERCE-NEIGE, je devrais éviter de parler trop vite, c'est une bonne façon de perde toute sa crédibilité...

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE Merci. Ça fait sept mois que j'apprends le français, alors c'est pas comme si je venais juste de m'y mettre, mais tout de même, je suis encore loin de maîtriser quoi que ce soit ! :)

Comment: C'est ce que je disais, pour 7 mois, c'est vraiment impressionnant. Il n'y a pas une seule faute dans ce que tu viens d'écrire, et tu parles comme n'importe quel francophone s'exprimerait. Si on peut communiquer par tchat ici, je veux en savoir plus sur ta méthode.

Comment: @Ahalone-zee Same, I will definitely contact you by email if that's ok :)

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Hi. Please feel free to contact me by email whenever you wish. That's exactly why I show my address in my profile in the first place. :)

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE Hi. Il ne s’agit que d’une méthode qui me réussit, rien de plus... Can we use email instead as a chat alternative? That’s always how I have an extended chat. If I kept this conversation going on a public chat, my colleagues would recognise me, which I wouldn’t want to happen! My address is as shown in my profile. :)

Comment: Les tchats sont privés ici, pas de souci pour te donner mon adresse, mais il faudra qu'on passe par un tchat pour que  je puisse te la donner.

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE Hi. Can you guide me to this tchat, as I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: I'm not very familiar either. Si tu t'inscris sur French language Meta, j'essayerai de t'inviter si j'y arrive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qui soi(ent) = that exist, existing in the world, qui exist(ent).

Un peu comme l'usage de "ever" en Anglais, on a un renforcement du sens:

It's the worst book. It's the worst book ever.

*Je lui donne les plus beaux légumes.*
*Je lui donne les plus beaux légumes qui soient*.

On a en plus du renforcement de sens, une certaine amélioration "esthétique" de la phrase. Elle est un peu plus littéraire que si on avait ajouté "du monde", ou autre.

Answer (score 0):

It would be grammatically correct, but the sentence would have an unusual meaning: why would they get the worst possible produce?

Instead, you can say

> Ils vendent les légumes les plus mauvais qui soient.

Answer (score 0):

"qui soit" / "qui soient" = "that exist(s)"

It's basically the same usage as "ever". The full phrase corresponding to "ever" would be something like "that has/have ever existed", like:

> They are selling the worst vegetables that have ever been grown.

In French, the full phrase would be "qui aient jamais existé", such as:

> Ils vendent les pires légumes qui aient jamais existé.

Note that "jamais" is usually translated by "never" when talking about a frequency, but this is also the right way to translate "ever".